# perform create: You cannot call `.save()` after accessing `serializer.data`

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am overriding CreateModelMixin with the following code:

```
 def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        with transaction.atomic():
            self.perform_create(serializer)
```

On the line  self.perform_create(serializer) i get the error:

```
"You cannot call `.save()` after accessing `serializer.data`."
```

Comment: Have you also overriden the `perform_create()` function? If not, you could just do `serializer.save()`. Also, you could surround the entire `create()` function with the `@transaction.atomic()` decorator instead of just using it in the end, just for the sake of trying.

Comment: @Shinratensei i get the same error "You cannot call `.save()` after accessing `serializer.data`."
AssertionError: You cannot call `.save()` after accessing `serializer.data`.If you need to access data before committing to the database then inspect 'serializer.validated_data' instead.

Comment: Weird. Are you trying to create nested serializations of objects? Such as an object that has a foreign key to another one, and you're also trying to serialize that other object?

Comment: What view does the Mixin applies to when you get the error ?